# How to select unique elements array from psobject?

Tags: powershell

```
$objs = @()

$obj = New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value "1"

$objs +=$obj.psobject.Copy()
$obj.name = "2"
$objs +=$obj.psobject.Copy()
$obj.name = "1"
$objs +=$obj.psobject.Copy()


$objs 

$objs | Select-Object -Unique

$objs
```

Comment: it would seriously help if you described what did not work as expected ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instruct `Select-Object` on what property it should look for uniqueness

```
$objs | Select-Object -Unique -Property Name
```